# Building predicate (NSExpression) to determine icon color for Mapbox SymbolStyle layer

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, predicate, nsexpression

I've recently started working with the Mapbox SDK on iOS and I've got some markers that I want to add to my map.  Each marker represents an object that has several properties, among them: a type property (which backs to an enum) and a boolean property.  I have a `MGLSymbolStyleLayer` defined and I've set most of the icon-related properties accordingly.  Currently, I'm  setting the icon color based solely on the "type" of the object like this:

```
let defaultColor = UIColor.blue
layer.iconColor = NSExpression(format: "MGL_MATCH(type, 'type1', %@, 'type2', %@, 'type3', %@, %@)", UIColor.orange, UIColor.purple, UIColor.yellow, defaultColor)
```

This is working well but now I need to add an additional piece of logic in the `NSExpression` to check the boolean property on each object and if it's true, then set the icon color to red; else, determine the icon color for each object based on it's type (using the logic defined above).  So in a nutshell, I need an `NSExpression` that functions like this:

```
if feature.booleanProperty == true {
   // set icon color to red
} else {
   // set icon color based on the feature type
}
```

I've looked through the Mapbox [Predicates and Expressions Reference](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/4.6.0/predicates-and-expressions.html) doc but it's still not clear to me how I would implement this sort of conditional logic in an `NSExpression`.  Can anyone tell me if this is possible to do and if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I tried:

```
NSExpression(format: "TERNARY(booleanProperty=YES, %@, MGL_MATCH(type, 'type1', %@, 'type2', %@, 'type3', %@, %@))", UIColor.red, UIColor.orange, UIColor.purple, UIColor.yellow, defaultColor)
```

SIDE NOTE: I tried only compositing ternary operators and evaluating on object, not this specific expression.

Comment: That does exactly what I need it to do!  I had tried TERNARY earlier today but apparently I misunderstood how to use it.  Thank you very much!

Comment: No surprise it wasn't clear to you - the documentation on this part of Mapbox is terrible.